# Can I use fingerprint reader to login through SonicWall

Tags: security, vpn, biometrics

One of the directors didnt know where to put his head. So he introduced new security measures. Now I have to type login and password every time I login into the office VPN (I work from home so it is annoying). It is SonicWall 4.9.

Is there a way to use a biometric device (eg fingerprint USB reader) so I can dupe SonicWall into getting my credentials from there and not from typing on the keyboard?

P.S. machine from which I login is not part of the domain and it is Windows 7. and SonicWall logs into office Windows domain.

Comment: [The feature](www.sonicwall.com/downloads/SSL_VPN-Two_factor_Authentication.pdf ) would have to be enabled onthe device itself.  Have you asked your IT about a possible solution?  We cannot for ethical reasons explain more notorious methods to get around the security process for obvious reasons.  Sounds like this director knows exactly he is doing, and it is you, who doesn't know where they belong.

Comment: I dont think RSA or Vasco devices can be read into the PC directly.. So I still have to type the code... I think ppl who give too much life advice simply the one who dont know much..

Comment: You have your answer then.  I provided documentation on the SonicWall on which 2-factor authentication methods it supports.